# Fréchet Derivative of a functional in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, frechet-derivative

I need to check if the functional $$ (f(x))(t):=\int_{0}^{1}k(s,t)\cdot \cos(x(t))dt $$ is Fréchet differentiable on $L^2([0,1])$, where $k:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. A function $f$ is Fréchet differentiable if and only if there is a bounded linear operator $T$ and a function h such that $$ f(x+u)=f(x)+T(u)+h(u)\text{, where }\lim\limits_{\Vert u\Vert \rightarrow 0}\frac{h(u)}{\Vert u\Vert}=0$$
My intuition would be that $f$ is not Fréchet differentiable. For $x,u\in L^2([0,1])$ using Taylor we get $$f(x+u)(s)=\int_{0}^{1}k(s,t)\cdot \cos((x+u)(t))dt=\int_{0}^{1}k(s,t)\cdot\left[\cos(x(t))-u(t)\cdot \sin(x(t))+\sigma(u(t)^2)\right]dt$$ where $\sigma(u^2) $ denotes the error term. If we compute this term we get $$f(x+u)(s)=f(x(s))+ \int_{0}^{1}-k(s,t)\cdot u(t)\cdot\sin(x(t))dt+\int_{0}^{1}k(s,t)\cdot\sigma (u(t)^2)dt$$ Define $T(u):=\int_{0}^{1}-k(s,t)\cdot u(t)\cdot\sin(x(t))dt$ and $h(u):=f(x+u)-f(x)-T(u)$. Clearly $T$ is linear and bounded, hence we have to check if $\lim\limits_{\Vert u\Vert \rightarrow 0}\frac{h(u)}{\Vert u\Vert}=0 $, that is $$\lim\limits_{\Vert u\Vert \rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{1}k(s,t)\left[\cos((x+u)(t))-\cos(x(t))+u(t)\cdot \sin(x(t))\right] dt}{\Vert u\Vert} = 0$$ I assume that the term blows up, but I have not been able to prove or disprove my assumption. Please any help with this question will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint : Taylor expansion with integral remainder

Comment: @jvc I tried that but I am having some problems with the concept of taylor expansion for a functional. By my understanding the Taylor expansion should look like $f(x+u)(s)=f(x(s))+u(s)\cdot f'(x(s))+\int_{x(s)}^{u(s)}f''(x(t))\cdot (x(s)-t)dt$, where $f'(x(s))=\int_{0}^{1}-k(s,t)\cdot sin(x(t))dt$ and $f''(x(s))=\int_{0}^{1}-k(s,t)\cdot cos(x(t))dt$, but that does not seem to be correct (or at least doesn't really help with the condition for the limites.

Comment: My idea was to use the Taylor expansion of cos with the integral remainder to show that the limit is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor-Lagrange inequality, for $a, b$ real numbers :
$|\cos(a+b) - \cos(a) - b \sin(a) |  \leq (M/2) b^2$
Thus, the ratio you consider is bounded by :
$$\int_0^1 |k(s, t)| M/2 |u(t)| dt \leq M/2 \| k(s,.) \|_2 \|u\|_2$$
(the second inequality if Holder)